# Is there a way to disable history for one command in TCSH?

Tags: freebsd, password, command-history, tcsh, csh

I am executing a command in TCSH, which requires me to pass a password on the command line. Obviously, I would like it not to be saved in the history file.

I know that other shells like Bash supports various ways to achieve it, like `export HISTCONTROL=ignorespace`.

Is there anything similar for TCSH (preferably on FreeBSD)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCSH does not support anything like this. The whole history of a shell session is merged to the history file when the shell is closed.

It is possible to skip a command from being added to the history file, however, by spawning another TCSH shell and unsetting `savehist`:

```
beastie@freebsd:~ $ csh
beastie@freebsd:~ $ echo First shell: $$
First shell: 7143
beastie@freebsd:~ $ exit
beastie@freebsd:~ $ tail -n 1 ~/.history
echo First shell: $$
beastie@freebsd:~ $ csh
beastie@freebsd:~ $ unset savehist
beastie@freebsd:~ $ echo Second shell: $$
Second shell: 74821
beastie@freebsd:~ $ exit
beastie@freebsd:~ $ tail -n 1 ~/.history
echo First shell: $$
```

As you can see, the command of the second shell were not appended to the history file.